# Simultaneous Update of multiple dependent lists via loop based on conditions Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a complex situation trying to solve but struggling to create logic and code for it.  Please consider the figure below:

[image]

Along the x-axis, I have number of iterations and y-axis I have nodes which are both user-defined and can change but considering 3-nodes and 5-iterations to keep it simple.

I am trying to create a looping frame-work or similar that can go through each node and based on the node number calculate a measure sequentially i.e., N0 then N1 and then N2.

For all nodes, the starting value is 'f_value' but subsequent values are dependent based on the node number. For example, Let us consider Node-0 denoted as 'N0'. First iteration depends on N0 last value as well as 'N1' last value which are both 'f_value'. Second iteration, for 'N0', we consider the last calculated value for 'N0' plus the previous value for 'N1' and this continues until the last iteration.

This gets more complex when considering nodes like 'N2' as we have to consider the latest value calculated for 'N0', last value for 'N2', and the previous value for 'N3'. When it comes to 'N3', we consider the last value for 'N3' and the latest value for 'N2' as shown in the picture. For the last node 'N3' we only consider the previous node 'N2'.

In other words, the first and last nodes have a single dependency but all the remaining nodes have multiple dependency i.e., nodes on both sides.

So far, I have managed to create a dictionary which creates the nodes and initialise the 'f_value' using the code below:

```
  node = list(range (int(input())))
obj = {}


for i, j in enumerate(node): # assigning default values
    obj['l'+str(i)] = [10]
```

I am struggling to take it further and requires some help which will be highly appreciated. I am thinking may be some conditional statements will be required but the problem is that you cannot update all the nodes simultaneously.

Please feel free to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


def iterate(f_value: float,
            number_of_nodes: int,
            number_of_iterations:int,
            weight_1: float = 0.5,
            weight_2: float = 0.2) -> list:
    """Itearates the f_value according to provided rule and returns the resulting array

    Args:

        f_value: user input value that will be iterated
        number_of_nodes: number of nodes that the iteration will run
        number_of_iterations: number of iterations
        weight_1: user provided weight, default is 0.5
        weight_2: user provided weight, default is 0.2

    Returns:
        A list with length=number_of_iterations where each element is a list that represents
        the corresponding row. Let's call returned list L. L[0][0] represents the value of
        iteration1, node1. L[0][1] represents iteration1 node2 and so on.

    Example:

        >>> iterate(10,3,5)
        [[7.0, 15.5, 17.75],
         [6.6, 22.35, 28.925],
         [7.7700000000000005, 32.02, 44.935],
         [10.289000000000001, 46.151500000000006, 68.01075],
         [14.374800000000002, 66.94105000000002, 101.48127500000001]]

        >>> L = iterate(10,3,5)
        >>> print(L[0][0])
        7.0
        >>> print(L[0][1])
        15.5

    """

    weight_1 = 0.5
    weight_2 = 0.2
    iterations = []


    C = f_value + (f_value * weight_2)
    
    for iteration_no in range(number_of_iterations):

        nodes = []
        
        for node_no in range(number_of_nodes):

            if iteration_no == 0:
                if node_no == 0:
                    # First node
                    value = f_value * (weight_1 + weight_2)

                elif node_no < number_of_nodes-1:
                    # Nodes in between
                    value = (nodes[node_no-1] / 2) + C


                else:
                    # Last node
                    value = (nodes[node_no-1] / 2) + f_value

                nodes.append(value)

            else:
                if node_no == 0:
                    # First node
                    value = (iterations[iteration_no-1][0] * weight_1) + (iterations[iteration_no-1][1] * weight_2)

                elif node_no < number_of_nodes-1:
                    # Nodes in between
                    # we need the latest iteration from [node_no -1]let
                    print
                    value = (iterations[iteration_no-1][node_no]) + (nodes[node_no-1] * weight_1) + (iterations[iteration_no-1][node_no+1] * weight_2)

                else:
                    # Last node
                    value = iterations[iteration_no-1][node_no] + (nodes[node_no-1] * weight_1)

                nodes.append(value)

        iterations.append(nodes)

    return iterations
```